# Best way to divide elements in a dictionary by the sum of columns C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary of ints:

```
        Dictionary<string, int[]> ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] b = { 3, 6, 9, 10, 12 };
        int[] c = {2,3,3,5,6};
        ret.Add("abc", a);
        ret.Add("def", b);
        ret.Add("ghi", c);
```

What is the best way to sum the values in each of the columns and then divide by the total? For example the first value would be 1/{1+3+2}

Here is what I tried but I think it sums by rows instead and it does not work because a type conversion error

```
public static Dictionary<string, double[]> freq(Dictionary<string, int[]> rawct)
    {

        Dictionary<string, double[]> scores = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int[]> kvp in rawct)
        {
            double[] percent = Array.ConvertAll(kvp.Value, x => (double)x);
            var total = (double)kvp.Value.Sum();

            var result = percent.Select(d => d / total);


            scores.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.value);
        }

        return scores;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to divide by the columns, i think you can do this (assumming all arrays are of the same size, in this example, 5 itens):

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> scores = ret.ToDictionary(r=> r.Key,
                         r => r.Value.Select((v, index)=> 
                         (double)v / ret.Values.Sum(values=> values[index]) // this is sum the columns
                         ).ToArray());
```

Output:

```
abc
    0,166666666666667
    0,181818181818182
    0,2
    0,210526315789474
    0,217391304347826
def
    0,5
    0,545454545454545
    0,6
    0,526315789473684
    0,521739130434783
ghi
    0,333333333333333
    0,272727272727273
    0,2
    0,263157894736842
    0,260869565217391
```

Comment: If I want to store this into a dictionary would I just do  `Dictionary<string, double[]> results = scores`?

Comment: indeed the type is Dictionary<string, double[]>, i edited to explicity declarion

Comment: there is an error in the type conversion at`ret.ToDictionary`

Comment: Look here what i got: http://rextester.com/GXEH51106 , it works fine, show me your code and how you are trying to convert.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studios and I am putting it into a function. I am getting this `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,double[]>'`

Comment: Forgot the .ToArray(), but i think you got at the rextestr, fixed :P